# Email not sending out excel attachment

Tags: python-3.x, email, error-handling, email-attachments, python-unicode

I am trying to send out emails with attachments to various recipients stored in a csv file. My aim is to send the recipients the corresponding attachment which is stored in a specific location.

The csv looks like this

```
Name,Emails,Firm
Tom,tom@fakedomian.com,Firm1
Dick,dick@fakedomain.com,Firm2
Harry,harry@fakedomain.com,Firm3
```

Within the folder the attachments would look like this

```
path='C:\\Documents\\Firms'
```

Within the location the files would look as follows

```
Firm1.xlsx
Firm2.xlsx
Firm3.xlsx
```

The following code uses the name and email in the csv to send out a personalised email while going through the folder to attach the corresponding excel file.

```
import email, csv, smtplib, ssl, fnmatch, os, codecs

from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import fnmatch

path = 'C:\\Documents\\Firms'
email_html = open('email.html')
body = email_html.read()


from_address = "youremail@domain.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")

#context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", 587) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_address, password)
    with open("Firms.csv") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)
        for Name, Email, Firm in reader:
            # Create a multipart message and set headers
            message = MIMEMultipart()
            message["From"] = from_address
            message["To"] = Email
            message["Subject"] = 'Test ' +  Name

            #Add body to email and excel attachment

            message.attach(MIMEText(body, "html"))

            for i in os.listdir(path):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,i)) and Firm in i:
                    with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rt', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as attachment:
                        part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
                        part.set_payload(attachment.read())

                        encoders.encode_base64(part)

                        part.add_header(
                        "Content-Disposition",f"attachment; filename= {Firm}",)

                    message.attach(part)
                    text = message.as_string()

                    # Use server to send email
                    server.sendmail(from_address, Email, text.format(name=Name))
```

Although this sends out emails the attachments are not in an excel format. When I used a encoding='utf8' I would get following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 18: character maps to <undefined>
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: is this occur during file read opertaion

Comment: Yes, it is. It gives a traceback error once it arrives here: part.set_payload(attachment.read())

Comment: try using 'rU' file mode with encoding utf8

Comment: Still get the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: try using rb mode

Comment: When I use rb mode it gives me following error message:  with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rb', encoding='utf8') as attachment:
ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: yes remove encoding

Comment: Tried that and gave me this error message:  with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rb','utf8') as attachment:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: at which line this error is thrown

Comment: Here: with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rb','utf8') as attachment:

Comment: try this import codecs  and replace with open as "codecs.open('your path to file', 'rU', 'utf-8').read()"

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. Just to clarify the issues are occurring in the second for loop were I'm iterating through the folder to attach the excel file corresponding to the Firm name in the csv file

Comment: The line should be: `with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rb') as attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to `import base64`. Then, try reading the file in binary mode. Specifically,

`with open(os.path.join(path, i), 'rb') as attachment:`

Then, you can read the contents of the file, encode it in base64, and then set this is as payload of the part, like:

`part.set_payload(base64.b64encode(attachment.read()))`

Of course remove the next line (`encoders.encode_base64(part)`), I think `encoders` is deprecated anyway.

I believe this should do the trick.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. This sends out email with attachments. Unfortunately, the attachments aren't in an excel format.

Comment: @mr.c Sorry for the late reply. If you are still trying to solve this, then 
 try `part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=Firm)`